# Can jitsu deploy multiple service units like juju's "add-unit" command?

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

EDIT: The essence of this question is: Can juju and/or jitsu do service co-location instead of having to use one node per service unit?

Does jitsu have a way to specify more than one particular machine to deploy multiple service units? For instance, I have ceph-mon deployed on three machines, but I want to deploy ceph-osd on the same three machines. As far as I can see, with jitsu I can only specify ONE machine for a particular service.

So, after doing:

```
jitsu deploy-to 1 --config local.yaml local:ceph-osd
```

I end up with:

```
services:
  ceph:
    charm: local:precise/ceph-91
    relations:
      mon:
      - ceph
    units:
      ceph/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1
        public-address: null
      ceph/1:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 2
        public-address: null
      ceph/2:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 3
        public-address: null
  ceph-osd:
    charm: local:precise/ceph-osd-7
    relations: {}
    units:
      ceph-osd/3:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1
        public-address: null
2013-05-06 11:22:09,165 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

Now it appears I have no way of adding ceph-osd service units to machines 2 and 3.

I would like to do something like add-unit and add in the other two machines.

p.s. Can't add it, but I suggest adding the tag "jitsu" to this board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response from jamespage and based on my other findings, I'd have to say the **answer to the question is currently no**. Let me explain.

I can do

```
juju deploy ceph -n 3
```

and juju will setup three nodes with Ceph, machines number 1, 2 and 3. I want to deploy Glance in 3 units across the same three nodes as Ceph. I can't do this. The most I can do is

```
jitsu deploy-to 1 glance
```

and Glance will be installed and configured on machine 1 where MySQL also lives. But if I want to scale Glance horizontally, I can't do an add-unit command, because jitsu doesn't currently support it. If I do:

```
juju add-unit glance
```

then a whole new node is taken, which is not the desired result, which is service co-location.

I would love to see that feature in jitsu! Specifically, you would be able to do:

```
jitsu deploy-to 1,2,3 -n 3 glance
```

and if you wanted to add units to this service, you could do:

```
jitsu deploy-to 4 add-unit glance
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about jitsu deploy-to supporting this feature, but you don't need to deploy the ceph-osd charm with the ceph charm in this way.

The ceph charm supports OSD functionality so can be deployed standalone; you can add extra storage capacity later if need be by using the ceph-osd charm.

Comment: Thanks, James. I'm following this:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA and it does state what you're saying as well. However, if I want to co-locate MySQL, RabbitMQ, Glance, Keystone, etc. on those same Ceph machines, I don't see a way to do that. jitsu only allows me to take a new service and deploy it to ONE machine. I want to deploy a new service to several machines that are already running other services. This is at the heart of my question.